# Convert decimal number to octal in Lisp

Tags: lisp, decimal, common-lisp, octal

I'm trying to write a function in Common Lisp to convert a base 10 number into a base 8 number, represented as a list, recursively.

Here's what I have so far:

```
(defun base8(n)
(cond
    ((zerop (truncate n 8)) (cons n nil))
    ((t) (cons (mod n 8) (base8 (truncate n 8))))))
```

This function works fine when I input numbers < 8 and > -8, but the recursive case is giving me a lot of trouble. When I try 8 as an argument (which should return `(1 0)`), I get an error `Undefined operator T in form (T)`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have forgotten to `(defun t ...)` or perhaps it's not the function `t` you meant to have in the cond? Perhaps it's `t` the truth value?

The dual namespace nature of Common Lisp makes it possible for t to both be a function and the truth value. the difference is which context you use it and you clearly are trying to apply `t` as a function/macro.

Here is the code edited for the truth value instead of the `t` function:

```
(defun base8(n)
  (cond
    ((zerop (truncate n 8)) (cons n nil))
    (t (cons (mod n 8) (base8 (truncate n 8))))))

(base8 8) ; ==> (0 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I did mean `t` to be the truth value. That fixed it so it works as I expect it to. Now I want to have the reverse list that I am returning. Is it possible to do this only in one function, or would I have to have a helper function?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out:

    (defun base8(n)
    (cond
        ((zerop (truncate n 8)) (cons n nil))
        (t (append (base8 (truncate n 8)) (cons (mod n 8)) nil)))))

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here's a solution without recursion, using built-in functionality:

```
(defun base8 (n)
  (reverse (coerce (format nil "~8R" n) 'list)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but specifically for the exercise, I don't think this is the most helpful.

Comment: Right.  It was soley for merriment.