# Define a recursive function to count the numbers of digits in a number in common lisp

Tags: recursion, common-lisp

This is what I did until now it tells me that it is not of type list.

```
(defun number_list(n)
  (setf x 
        (if (zerop (truncate n 10)) 
          (list n)
          (append (number_list (truncate n 10)) (list (mod n 10)))))
  (length x))
```

When I remove the (length x) I can see that the result is a list however.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: One problem with you code is that with `(length x)`, the result is _not_ a list anymore. For a solution: see uselpa's answer.

Comment: You may be also interested in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892507 that aside, it is possible to greatly speed-up the algorithm by using `integer-length` which returns number of bits in the integer. But if you are only interested in `fixnum`, then a table would do best (there are all in all 19 digits in `max-positive-fixnum`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution uses a global variable `x`, which is generally a bad idea, especially in recursive functions. Then, you create a list in order to count the number of digits. This is not really necessary.

**Using a list**

If you want to work with a list, I suggest you split the problem in 2 parts:

*1. convert a number to a list*

Your function works well for this if you remove `setf x`:

```
(defun number_list(n)
  (if (zerop (truncate n 10)) 
    (list n)
    (append (number_list (truncate n 10)) (list (mod n 10)))))
```

*2. count the number of digits*

```
(defun numdigits (n)
  (length (number_list n))).
```

**Alternative**

But I would suggest a simple recursive definition such as:

```
(defun numdigits (n)
  (if (< -10 n 10)
    1
    (1+ (numdigits (truncate n 10)))))
```

Comment: using append in a recursive function to add an element to the end of a list should be avoided

Comment: oh, thank you. I just could not figure out how to use length with my function. So this is how you get the data from the first function.

Comment: @user2976636 One problem with your function is that sometimes it returns a list, and sometimes a number. If you separate the two then the solution is easy.

Comment: This works and fulfills the specific question asked, although I would probably go for `(defun num-digits (n &optional (base 10)) (ceiling (log (1+ n) base)))` as long as I can guarantee that n is 1 or higher (one could, I guess, special-case 0).

Comment: @Vatine My personal favorite would be `(defun numdigits (n) (length (write-to-string (abs n))))` but that doesn't answer the OP's question either.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the decimal digits and then count the length, assuming that numbers are 0 or greater integers.

```
(defun number-list (n) 
  (if (< n 10) 
      (list n)
    (cons (mod n 10)
          (number-list (truncate n 10)))))

CL-USER 44 > (length (number-list 123456789))
9
```

But it is preferable to directly count the digits. See the other answers.